# PTIJ: cholent bath?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I was learning Ramba”m Mishnah Torah (Hilchos shabbos perek 2 halchah 2) and I saw a very confusing sentence:

“וּמְחִמִּין לוֹ חַמִּין בֵּין לְהַשְׁקוֹתוֹ בֵּין לִרְחִיצַת גּוּפוֹ.”- and they heat him cholent, whether to drink, or to bathe him.
I understand why they would heat him cholent to drink (although “to eat” would make more sense), but why would someone want to bathe in cholent?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Why *wouldn’t* someone want to bathe in cholent? VTC as unclear. :)

Comment: I don’t think it would be very comfortable

Comment: It's a typo. It should say "**Lertzichas** gufo". Eat some Cholent and you'll see why

Comment: It does say lertzichas gufo...

Comment: @Loani, No, it says "*lerchitzas* gufo"

Comment: Wait, so you’re saying we can heat up cholent “to kill his body”? That doesn’t sound right

Comment: @Loani Clearly you’ve never spilled cholent on yourself before. Really hot, spicy cholent that you spilled on yourself, simultaneously burning your mouth, esophagus, and skin. It’s 1/60 of the fate which met Nadav and Avihu.

Comment: Yes but ramba”m says that we heat it specifically “to kill him”— why would the ramba”m want you to burn your throat?

Answer (score 1):

There's a commonality between chulent and hot baths. Both are relaxing and they both promote sleep.

So, on Shabbat, it's a mitzvah to sleep. But, it's tough to take a hot bath as there are many possible melachot violations that could occur in doing this. But, if the cholent is already hot, one may bathe in it and enjoy a hot bath in the chulent so that he can sleep better on Shabbat.

I like this idea. It really is a win-win situation. So, you can have your chulent and eat and bathe in it, too!

Comment: In context, the Rambam refers to a sick person. Even if not, seemingly this would be a מלאכה שאינה צריכה לגופה, as you’re warming up the cholent for the heat, not the food.

Comment: @DonielF If you would, check Ramba"m and other sources. I sense that anyone would permit heated food for other usage. I.e., your main purpose is heating the chulent for food. After you've eaten it, why can't you take some out the pot to use for the bath?

Comment: Surely if it was heated up already there would be no problem. I meant warming it up specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @DonielF My answer addresses using the chulent for dual purpose. I think it' s clear, but, if not, I can edit it. Note that I said, "if it's already hot".

Comment: @DanF The language of the Rambam makes it clear that it's permitted for either/or.

Comment: @DonielF, doesn't Rambam hold מלאכה שא״צ לגופה חייב?

Comment: @msh210 I dunno, does he? I thought everyone held פטור אבל אסור